# How do I play a tone using the j2mw media API?

Tags: java, audio, java-me, media

I want to play a tone using the j2me media api but I can't seem to hear any tone when I run the program..How do I play a tone using the API?

```
Manager.playTone(ToneControl.C4, 4000, 100000);
                    //Player player = Manager.createPlayer(wav);
                System.out.println("Played ");
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for the [How to play tone](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/J2ME/ToneMIDlet.htm), Also check whether your device is set to play sound from java app, and its not in silent mode.